# Does Windows Server Domain have any feature that will wipe out a client computer?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

A Windows 7 Professional laptop is joined into a Windows Domain during setup and installation in the office network in country X, but it is being used in another country for a long period of time without access to the office network.

If for a long time the laptop does not get a chance to athenticate with the domain controller in country X, will the Windows 7 OS wipe out the system and remove all applications and files?

I am familiar with seeing the option to wipe out the mobile system when configuring Exchange on mobile device.

I am thinking if this also happens to Windows in general. This is what seems to be happening to a client laptop we have now. This is the third time on 3 different laptops.

Answer (score 1):

There exists no option to cause a windows 7 computer to format itself if it doesn't see a domain controller for some period of time.  It's extremely unlikely that this is happening as you imply - more likely there is a profile issue and the user, seeing their desktop and documents folder empty, incorrectly reports that everything has been deleted.